# Where is the Darwin term in Griffiths quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, quantum-spin, perturbation-theory, hydrogen

I was reading the Wikipedia page on [fine structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine_structure#Total_effect), and it had the following expression for the fine structure of Hydrogen:
[image: Wiki description of fine structure corrections]
To recap the image, Wikipedia includes the spin-orbit interaction, the first relativistic kinetic energy correction, and the Darwin term.

The expression of the perturbation to the energies matches that given in Griffiths' quantum mechanics textbook:
[image: Griffiths quantum mechanics]

To recap the image, as far as I can tell, Griffiths only includes the spin-orbit interaction and first relativistic kinetic energy correction, and not the Darwin term.

---

Is it true that Griffiths does not include the Darwin term? If so, how does he find the same fine structure as that given in Wikipedia?

---

I suspect it's from Griffiths playing a little fast and loose with the $l=0$ states in the spin-orbit coupling - the spin-orbit coupling should be identically zero for $l=0$, but I believe he gives it a nonzero value. Exactly the $l=0$ states are affected by the Darwin term, so I think this may be the resolution. Indeed, there's a somewhat evasive footnote:
[image: Griffiths footnote 18 in chapter 7]
To recap the footnote, it doesn't mention the Darwin term but instead directs the reader to the Dirac equation. Since the Darwin term is derivable from the Dirac equation, I think this is evidence for the picture I'm painting above.

Comment: Yeah, that's precisely what Griffiths is doing. He's doing a derivation that doesn't work for $\ell = 0$ but it gives the right result for $\ell = 0$ because the Darwin term  plays a role there.

Comment: @knzhou Good to see the confirmation, and feel free to post it as an answer. As an aside, it feels like these two errors cancelling out is something of an accident stemming from the special properties of the Coulomb potential of a point charge (i.e. Laplacian of it is a delta function). I wonder whether it depends on dimension much - I'm curious if (4+1)d Griffiths could make the same pair of errors that cancel out.

Comment: Well, the Laplacian of a point charge field is always going to be a delta function in any dimension, since the point charge field varies with dimension too.

Comment: I think the deeper underlying point is that there's a proper derivation going from the Dirac equation that does the whole thing in one step, without having to define a bunch of separate pieces which combine in a tricky way. And that derivation is going to give something nice and analytic in $\ell$.

Comment: @knzhou I agree! By dimensional analysis, I think they should give similar $\frac{1}{a^d}$ contributions, with $a$ the Bohr radius, though I suppose that angular momentum being a two-form and the introduction of more quantum numbers might muddy the story a little bit.